# How to set css width or left attributes to get pixel perfect result?

Tags: javascript, css

I just started experimenting with JS/CSS a bit and I came across this problem I couldn't find an answer for on the forum.

I wonder how I could get rid off the white line in the middle of the window (picture attached). It doesn't appear all the time but at certain scalings.

Many thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .d {
        position: fixed;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0px;

        background-color: #A1F1F1;
        text-align: center;


    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <script>

    var numOfDivsHor = 10;
    var numOfDivsVer = 10;

    function setCubeSize() {

        document.body.innerHTML = '';

        var w = document.body.clientWidth;
        var h = document.body.clientHeight;
        var fs = h/numOfDivsVer/3;

        for (i=0; i < numOfDivsHor; i++) {
            for (j=0; j < numOfDivsVer; j++) {
                var d = document.createElement('div');
                document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(d);

                d.id = i + '' + j;
                d.className = 'd';
                d.innerHTML = i + '' + j;

                setLayout(i + '' + j, w, h, fs);

                d.style.left = j * w/numOfDivsHor + 'px';
                d.style.top = i * h/numOfDivsVer + 'px';
                d.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(120, ' + Math.round(i * 25.5) + ', ' + Math.round(j * 25.5) + ')';
            }

        }

    }

    function setLayout(divId, w, h, fs) {
        var d = document.getElementById(divId);
        d.style.width = 100/numOfDivsHor + '%';
        d.style.height = 100/numOfDivsVer + '%';
        d.style.fontSize = fs + 'px';
        d.style.paddingTop = (h/numOfDivsVer - fs)/2 + 'px';

    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {;
        setCubeSize();
    });

    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        setCubeSize();
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[white line in the middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMV5x.png)

Comment: Could you include your HTML? Cant' do much without it.

Comment: This is the html, css + js code. All in one.

Comment: I can not get your code to run correctly in a fiddle. Could you post a working version? It's good practice to always include a working, reproducible version of the problem you're trying to fix.

Comment: @LeeA. It works find as an HTML source though. The white lines appear when resizing the page and can remain depending on what the final resized width is left at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a rounding issue that is common when dealing with graphics and floating point numbers. You more or less just need to `floor` values when you divide.

Specifically, this change fixes the problem in the code that you posted. Change:

```
d.style.left = j * w/numOfDivsHor + 'px';
d.style.top = i * h/numOfDivsVer + 'px';
```

to:

```
d.style.left = j * Math.floor(w/numOfDivsHor) + 'px';
d.style.top = i * Math.floor(h/numOfDivsVer) + 'px';
```

Note that you will be left with whitespace on one edge of the grid. This is because the size of the window is not a perfect multiple of the size of a cell. You have to choose either between keeping the sizes of the cells the same, as above, or having varying sizes of cell, which would take a bit more work.

Comment: thank you! This really helped. I'll try your approach on the "whitespace on the edge" issue. Thanks!